# How can I configure Entity Framework to automatically trim values retrieved for specific columns mapped to char(N) fields?

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework, trim, entity-framework-6

I'm working with a third-party database in which all text values are stored as `char(n)`. Some of these text values are primary keys, whereas others are just normal human-readable text. For the latter, I want retrieved values to be automatically trimmed.

I know I can add `Trim` to all of my LINQ to Entities queries, but this is messy, unreliable and unmaintainable. I would like to somehow configure Entity Framework to automatically trim values retrieved from specific columns.

However, I don't know how to do this. I'm using EF's fluent API. The closest thing I've thought of so far is creating additional properties to wrap the real properties with `Trim` method calls, but this is messy and still not very maintainable. I would also prefer for the trimming to occur in the database rather than the application.

Comment: Looks like a [Garbage in, Garbage out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) problem.  You may want to just do this one time only in the database, then never worry about it again.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, from memory, I was working against an existing database. Are you suggesting I change the column types from `char` to `varchar` to eliminate the source of the problem? Sounds good, but I rarely am given the liberty to make changes like that! :)

Comment: Yes, if it wasn't a char and was (n)varchar then this wouldn't be an issue for you or anyone else.  Padding was necessary a long time ago.for paging, the fact that it remains today is legacy.  It's scary for me to see people still using it today.

Comment: Just wondering if, after nearly 5 years, my answer is good enough, it could be marked as the answer? ;)

Comment: @StuartGrassie, sorry Stuart, but I don't use EF anymore and haven't had time to verify your answer. One of the flaws in the way the SO system works. :)

Answer (score 41):

Rowan Miller (program manager for Entity Framework at Microsoft) recently posted a good solution to this which uses Interceptors. Admittedly this is only valid in EF 6.1+. His post is about trailing strings in joins, but basically, the solution as applied neatly removes trailing strings from all of the string properties in your models, automatically, without noticeably affecting performance.

Original blog post: [Working around trailing blanks issue in string joins](http://romiller.com/2014/10/20/ef6-1workaround-trailing-blanks-issue-in-string-joins/)

The relevant code is reposted here, but I encourage you to read his blog post. (Also if you use EF, you should read his blog anyway).

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception;
using System.Linq;

namespace FixedLengthDemo
{
    public class StringTrimmerInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
    {
        public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
        {
            if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult.DataSpace == DataSpace.SSpace)
            {
                var queryCommand = interceptionContext.Result as DbQueryCommandTree;
                if (queryCommand != null)
                {
                    var newQuery = queryCommand.Query.Accept(new StringTrimmerQueryVisitor());
                    interceptionContext.Result = new DbQueryCommandTree(
                        queryCommand.MetadataWorkspace,
                        queryCommand.DataSpace,
                        newQuery);
                }
            }
        }

        private class StringTrimmerQueryVisitor : DefaultExpressionVisitor
        {
            private static readonly string[] _typesToTrim = { "nvarchar", "varchar", "char", "nchar" };

            public override DbExpression Visit(DbNewInstanceExpression expression)
            {
                var arguments = expression.Arguments.Select(a =>
                {
                    var propertyArg = a as DbPropertyExpression;
                    if (propertyArg != null && _typesToTrim.Contains(propertyArg.Property.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name))
                    {
                        return EdmFunctions.Trim(a);
                    }

                    return a;
                });

                return DbExpressionBuilder.New(expression.ResultType, arguments);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Rowan continues: "Now that we have an interceptor, we need to tell EF to use it. This is best done via Code-Based Configuration. We can just drop the following class in the same assembly/project as our context and EF will pick it up."

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace FixedLengthDemo
{
    public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public MyConfiguration()
        {
            AddInterceptor(new StringTrimmerInterceptor());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to use the StringLength attribute on my model but this approach did work for me.

Comment: Please use this with caution. We deployed this exact solution and it brought our website to its knees with CPU usage. Profiler showed it to be the cause, and removing it removed the problem. I'm sure the effect is related to application specific workload, but be advised that this is a very CPU intensive solution.

Comment: This mechanism showed real promise. Unfortunately something either has changed or I'm doing it wrong, but it's not working for me. :< It's not getting into the string trimming interceptor calls.

Comment: @PHenry if you are using Entity Framework Core than this answer is mostly likely not going to apply, it's fairly specific to EF 6.1+ to 6.4.

Answer (score 35):

If you are using **Entity Framework Core**, you can use `Conversion` like this:

```
entity.Property(e => e.Name)
             .HasConversion(
                new ValueConverter<string, string>(v => v.TrimEnd(), v => v.TrimEnd()));
```

Comment: The cleanest solution :)

Answer (score 12):

Use properties with backing fields instead of automatic properties on your entities.

Add the "Trim()" in the property setter, like so:

```
    protected string _name;
    public String Name
    {
        get { return this._name; }
        set { this._name = (value == null ? value : value.Trim()); }
    }
```

I wrote my own POCO generator that just does this automatically, but if you don't have an option like that, ReSharper can add backing fields to automatic properties in like two keystrokes. Just do it for strings, and you can do a global (at the file scope) find/replace for " `= value;`" with "`= value.Trim();`".

Comment: It's bettet to check null first so I'd do it that way:
set { _name = (value == null ? null : value.Trim());}

Comment: Starting with C# 6.0 the setter can be nicely simplified using the null-conditional operator: `set { this._name = value?.Trim(); }`

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework does not supply hooks to change the way it composes SQL statements, so you can't tell it to fetch *and* Trim string fields from the database.

It would be possible to trim string properties in the `ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized` event, but I think this would greatly affect performance. Also, it would take a lot of `if-else` or `switch` code to do this for *specific* properties (as you intend to do). But it could be worth a try if you want to do this for nearly all properties (except the keys, for instance).

Otherwise I would go for the additional properties.

Comment: This is no longer true in EF 6.1. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. And I resolved it by this simple way in DbContext:

```
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var entity in this.ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            foreach (PropertyEntry property in entity.Properties.ToList().Where(o => !o.Metadata.IsKey()))
                TrimFieldValue(property);
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    private void TrimFieldValue(PropertyEntry property)
    {
        var metaData = property.Metadata;
        var currentValue = property.CurrentValue == null ? null : property.CurrentValue.ToString();
        var maxLength = metaData.GetMaxLength();

        if (!maxLength.HasValue || currentValue == null) return;

        if (currentValue.Length > maxLength.Value)
            property.CurrentValue = currentValue.Substring(0, maxLength.Value);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Please note that you do not `Trim` but `Truncate` the string.

Answer (score 1):

I relied on [Pavel Lobkov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55495444/19548687)'s solution and got the result with this:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        TrimFieldValue();

        return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        TrimFieldValue();

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    private void TrimFieldValue()
    {
        foreach (var entity in this.ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            foreach (PropertyEntry property in entity.Properties.ToList().Where(o => o.Metadata.ClrType.Name.Equals("String") && o.CurrentValue is not null))
            {
                var currentValue = property.CurrentValue.ToString();
                property.CurrentValue = currentValue.Trim();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I used the approach given by Stuart Grassie but it didn't work at first because the column type only contained the "char","varchar" etc. The columns are actually "char(30)", "varchar(10)", etc. Once I changed the line that follows it worked like a charm!

from:
`if (propertyArg != null && _typesToTrim.Contains(propertyArg.Property.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name))`

to:
`if (propertyArg != null && _typesToTrim.Any(t => propertyArg.Property.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name.Contains(t)))`

Thanks Stuart!

Comment: This doesn't look like a valid answer because you're basically using the same solution Stuart added + a slightly different case, I suggest you add it as a comment in Stuart's question.