# Entity Framework 7 Interceptor : Convert the Value while retrieving for Specified Column for DateTime datatype

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i have look into this link, same kind of conversion has to be implement for datetime

[How can I configure Entity Framework to automatically trim values retrieved for specific columns mapped to char(N) fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133696/how-can-i-configure-entity-framework-to-automatically-trim-values-retrieved-for)

Code:

```
 public class ConvertToLocalDateTime : DefaultExpressionVisitor
 {
  private static readonly string[] _typesToTrim = { "varchar", "datetime", String" };
  public override DbExpression Visit(DbNewInstanceExpression expression)
    {
        var arguments = expression.Arguments.Select(a =>
        {
            var propertyArg = a as DbPropertyExpression;
            if (propertyArg != null && _typesToTrim.Contains(propertyArg.Property.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name))
            {

                DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(a);                    
                DbExpression outPutExp = dt.ToLocalTime();
                return outPutExp;
               // return EdmFunctions.Trim(a);

            }

            return a;
        });

        return DbExpressionBuilder.New(expression.ResultType, arguments);
    }
}
```

In the above code, am unable to convert "a" to Datatime.

Thanks

Comment: can you plz, write your exception stack trace.

Comment: "a" in your code is a DbPropertyExpresssion, you probably need the value instead.

Comment: And what is EntityFramework 7?

Comment: @TGlatzer- Yes, i need to get the value and need convert to Datetime.ToLocal
and am using EntityFramework.6.1.3