# Adding and Removing interceptors in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am facing a trailing space issue in joining tables through Entity Framework. 
With this below post, I could handle the space trimming in Entity Framework level through the interceptor
[How can I configure Entity Framework to automatically trim values retrieved for specific columns mapped to char(N) fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133696/how-can-i-configure-entity-framework-to-automatically-trim-values-retrieved-for)

However, I would not require this is in EF level. I need that just for a query. 
I can see there is an `AddInterceptor` function. I don't know how to unsubscribe or remove the interceptor after the query execution.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

There is the `DbInterception.Remove` method in the `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception` namespace.