# EF6.1.2 code first with 2 navigation properties both are one to zero to one, one works, but the other does not work

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, pervasive

I have 3 tables, one is kind of the base table and is big.
Then I have an extension table which is also big 
Then I have a tiny table with only one attribute except for the PK

In essence the primary key for all 3 tables is the same, except for the name
first table :

```
[Table("KLANTEN")]
public class Klant
{
    public Klant()
    {
        this.ContactPersonen = new HashSet<ContactPersoon>();
        this.Afleveringen = new HashSet<Aflever>();
    }

    [Key]
    [StringLength(8000)]
    public string NUMMER { get; set; }

    .... removed for brevity

    #region Navigation Properties
    public virtual Aanspreking Aanspreking { get; set; }
    public virtual PuntenKlant PuntenKlant { get; set; } // fail
    public virtual ExtraVeldenKlant ExtraVeldenKlant { get; set; } //ok 
    public virtual ICollection<ContactPersoon> ContactPersonen { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Aflever> Afleveringen { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

second table:

```
[Table("EXVKLA")]
public class ExtraVeldenKlant
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(8000)]
    public string NUMMER { get; set; }

    ... removed for brevity

    #region Navigation Properties
    public virtual Klant Klant { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

third table:

```
[Table("[_CTPUNT]")]
public class PuntenKlant
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(8000)]
    public string KODE { get; set; }

    [StringLength(8000)]
    public string OMSCHR { get; set; }

    #region Navigation Properties
    public virtual Klant Klant { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

As you see the key is defined alsways on the first column not using the fluent api. I like it that way and the way I understood it, fluent api and attribute syntax can be mixed right ?

So for the configuration i am doing this :

```
class KlantConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Klant>
{
    public KlantConfiguration()
    {
        .... removed for brevity

        this.HasMany(e => e.ContactPersonen)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Klant)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.KLANTCODE)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        this.HasMany(e => e.Afleveringen)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Klant)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.KLANTCODE)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        this.HasOptional(e => e.PuntenKlant)
            .WithRequired(f => f.Klant);

        this.HasOptional(e => e.ExtraVeldenKlant)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Klant);
    }
}
```

executing following SQL statement just to verify everything is in place :

```
select klanten.nummer,P.KODE,E.NUMMER,p.OMSCHR from klanten
inner join "_CTPUNT" P on P.KODE=klanten.nummer
inner join exvkla E on E.NUMMER=klanten.nummer 
where klanten.nummer='000002'
```

results in :

```
NUMMER     KODE     NUMMER     OMSCHR                                  
========   ======   ========   ========================================
000002     000002   000002     571
```

So this proves that they key is present in all three tables

Now if I try this using the real stuff in EF :

```
var puntenquery =
      from p in repoKlant.Queryable().Include("PuntenKlant").Include("ExtraVeldenKlant")
      where p.NUMMER == "000002"
      select p;
```

then i get the weird result that the navigation property PuntenKlant is null
But the navigation property ExtraVeldenKlant is properly filled in.
I fail the see where i am going wrong.
Debugging EF shows that the query is in fact correctly executed but it is quite large, but the fields from that particular navigation property are int the query that is generated by EF. Though it looks as if through the materialisation process it does not work.

What am i doing wrong or is there a bug in EF, or in the pervasive ADO.NET driver, this is not SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

OK it seems I had to change the underlying database a bit.
the lenght of the keyfield in one of the tables was shorter.
Man I had a hell of a time today to solve this freeking problem.

And this link is the perfect solution : 
[How can I configure Entity Framework to automatically trim values retrieved for specific columns mapped to char(N) fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133696/how-can-i-configure-entity-framework-to-automatically-trim-values-retrieved-for)

So I don't have to change anything in the database.