# Why is SingleOrDefault not returning the whole entity graph

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get the whole graph of an entity `User`. The `User` class is:

**Updated**

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string email_address { get; set; }

    [Column("Password Hash")]
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    public string custnmbr { get; set; }        

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

My `Customer` Class:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public string Custnmbr { get; set; }

    public string Custname { get; set; }        

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I have this in my DbContext:

```
public class EntityContext : DbContext
{
    public EntityContext(DbContextOptions<EntityContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne<Customer>(u => u.Customer)
            .WithMany(c => c.Users)
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.custnmbr);
    }
}
```

My UserService:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly EntityContext _context;
            
    public UserService(EntityContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _context.Users.Include("Customer").Load();
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> GetAll()
    {
        var users = _context.Users.Local.ToList();
        return users;
    }

    public User GetByUsername(string emailAddress)
    {
        var user = _context.Users.Local.SingleOrDefault(x => x.email_address == emailAddress);
        return user;
    }        
}
```

My UserControler:

```
[Route("api/Users")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public UsersController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    [HttpGet("GetAll")]
    public IActionResult GetAll()
    {
        var users = _userService.GetAll();
        return Ok(users);
    }

    [HttpGet("GetUser")]
    public IActionResult GetUser(string emailAddress)
    {
        var user = _userService.GetByUsername(emailAddress);
        return Ok(user);
    }
}
```

And GetAll() returns the whole graph for all `Users`. But GetUser() returns a single `User` with property `Customer` null.

How can I get the whole `User` graph including the property `Customer`?

Any help would be appreciated.

*Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 - Version 16.10.3*

*Microsoft.AspNetCore (5.0.0)*

*Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (5.0.7)*

Comment: Isn't it because the `NotMapped` attribute is explicitly set on `Customer` property?

Comment: @Crono, I removed `NotMapped` and `Customer` property is still null.

Comment: You need to create a new migration and apply it after removing `[NotMapped]` attribute.

Comment: @LazZiya I am not using migrations

Comment: Please update your question to share a [mcve] _without_ `NotMapped`.

Comment: Most likely "Load" ignores "Include". Idea of Load is to "load" entities of one type, hence you you should Load both Customers and Users separately and only then Include when you doing actual query

Comment: @NikitaChayka I added `_context.Customers.Load()` to the UserService Constructor. I even switched to `var user = _context.Users.Include("Customer").SingleOrDefault(x => x.email_address == emailAddress)` in GetUser() and the `Customer` property is still null.

Comment: @Randy, so then are you sure that you have related record in database then?

Comment: @NikitaChayka Yes, the `Customer` property shows when I run GetAll() in the exact same UserService.

Comment: I have tried to use `var user = _context.Users.Where(x => x.email_address == emailAddress).Include(x => x.Customer).FirstOrDefault()` in GetUser() like on [entityframeworktutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/querying-in-ef-core.aspx) Eager Loading.

Comment: is the ForeignKey [custnmbr] return in the result?

Comment: @mustafahassan Yes it is returned in the result

Comment: BTW it's questionable why you always load all users. It'll happen each time the controller is created, i.e. for each request. And `GetUser` only needs to load one user. You may as well execute the db query when it's actually requested.

Comment: @GertArnold I have used `var user = _context.Users.Where(x => x.email_address == emailAddress).Include(x => x.Customer).FirstOrDefault()` like I said in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, but I consider the question as reflecting the current status of what you're asking. Comments are many and inconclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I want to apologize to the StackOverflow community. This was my dumb mistake.

Using this [How can I configure Entity Framework to automatically trim values retrieved for specific columns mapped to char(N) fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133696/how-can-i-configure-entity-framework-to-automatically-trim-values-retrieved-for)

I found out my own mistake. I needed to add this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .Property(e => e.Custnmbr)
            .HasConversion(new ValueConverter<string, string>(v => v.TrimEnd(), v => v.TrimEnd()));
```

to the `OnModelCreating()` of my EntityContext. I had trailing spaces in some of the `Custnmbr` properties.

Problem solved.