# With a legacy MSSQL database that is using Char instead of varchar my Entity Framework Core is returning padded strings

Tags: entity-framework-core, char, blazor, varchar

I am working with a legacy MSSQL database that is using Char instead of Varchar for its string fields.  But when I bring the data into my Blazor application using Entity Framework Core, my strings are all padded with spaces which causes all sorts of issues.

Is there a way to have this conversion happen automatically or is there an annotation I can add to my EF Core model class string fields to do this conversion?

Comment: https://romiller.com/2014/10/20/ef6-1workaround-trailing-blanks-issue-in-string-joins/

Comment: The database explicitly uses fixed-length strings. The strings **are already padded**, although due to SQL quirks that may not be apparent. If you store `'A'` in a `char(4)` field, it behaves as `'A  '`.

Answer (score 1):

You could `alter` that legacy field from `CHAR(123)` into `VARCHAR(123)`. This will probably not cause any backwards compatibility issue, it will save space for you and you will get rid of the paddings as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found this finally [How can I configure Entity Framework to automatically trim values retrieved for specific columns mapped to char(N) fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133696/how-can-i-configure-entity-framework-to-automatically-trim-values-retrieved-for)

Adding this to my EF core modelbuilder on the Char properties solved the problem:

```js
entity.Property(e => e.Name)
             .HasConversion(
                new ValueConverter<string, string>(v => v.TrimEnd(), v => v.TrimEnd()));
```

Comment: That's a bad and very expensive idea. This means you end up with orphaned temporary strings every time you try to read a string value. Why not switch to `varchar` ? And if the database uses fixed-length strings, why treat them as something different in the client application?